# How to start on query tuning?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

looking for advice on how to start with Oracle tuning, I've never done it before.

I'd like to know how to do performance tuning of queries. We build applications for clients, so I don't have production database here. I basically know which of our queries are important, and want to make sure they will run fast.

In MSSQL it is pretty straight-forward, when you enable execution plan, it shows additional indexes which will help the query.  Is there anything similar to that in Oracle? Or perhaps another approach?

Comment: I would start with logging the query execution plans. Capturing the SQL workload is also an interesting option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Performance tuning is a big subject. There are two basic types of approaches that people take: **science** or **guesswork**.

**A. Guesswork** (otherwise known as the **shotgun** approach)

1. Look at the query
2. Guess which columns need indexes that don't have them already `*`
3. Create the indexes and re-run the query
4. If it made no difference, go back to step 1 and repeat.

**B. Science**

1. Find out how fast the query "should" be.
2. Determine how fast the query actually is (under "realistic" conditions as far as possible).
3. If it's already fast enough, stop here. Otherwise:
4. Determine where most of the time is going - is it spinning or waiting?
5. If it's waiting, find out what it's waiting for, and eliminate that if possible.
6. If it's spinning, find out what it's doing that it doesn't need to do, and eliminate that if possible.
7. Go back to step 2 and repeat.

(`*` if there are no more indexes to create, look for something else to change - anything. e.g. change a few session or system settings, rebuild a table, etc.)

(`***` in case it's not obvious, I'm *not* advocating approach A)

Answer (score -1):

First thing I would suggest is if you are not going to do tuning on prod databases you should import the table statics from prod db to your Dev one. This will make your Dev system behave as it has similar data as prod. If you google for importing stats you will find loads of articles. The next stage would to look at queries where u can add indexes generally where you see full table scan is a good place to look.

Do you use Bind variables?

Oracle does a lot of caching data so see where you can use bind variables this will do filtering in the private space of server process and save the db from doing physical reads and hence data is returned quickly.

Hope this helps.